# how to store the query result into an array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

this is my model code.i have to store these values into an array.someone please help with it.

```
    $this->db->select('value,T_Id,T_MId,T_DID,T_Date,T_UOM');
    $this->db->from('mapping,main');
    $this->db->where('main.Id=mapping.S_ID');
    $this->db->where('main.MId=mapping.S_MId');
    $this->db->where('main.DID=mapping.S_DID');
    $this->db->where('main.Date=mapping.S_Date');
    $this->db->where('main.UOM=mapping.S_UOM');
    $qu1 = $this->db->get();
    $n=$qu1->num_rows();
    echo $n;
    $a = $qu1->result_array();
    print_r($a);
```

Comment: So whats wrong in this, it looks perfect. `$a` is array in your code.

Comment: You can also use in following way : 

$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
$result = $query->result_array();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

Comment: i don't know how to proceed with this array. now i have to take the 
*value* .how to do it?

Comment: please add output in your question

Comment: Have you checked this query in mysql ?
Please check it with "echo $this->db->last_query();"

Comment: "how to proceed with this array" means do you want it in controller then  If you have got array then return it to controller.

Comment: @hrishi   yes. that is what i want.

Comment: then return $a; in model. in controller suppose you have called model as $data = $this->model->function();  then you will get array in $data.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add return statement at the end of this code ,Please check the code:

```
 public function YourFunctionName(){
    $arrReturn = array();//Declare the array to be passed
    $this->db->select('value,T_Id,T_MId,T_DID,T_Date,T_UOM');
    $this->db->from('mapping,main');
    $this->db->where('main.Id=mapping.S_ID');
    $this->db->where('main.MId=mapping.S_MId');
    $this->db->where('main.DID=mapping.S_DID');
    $this->db->where('main.Date=mapping.S_Date');
    $this->db->where('main.UOM=mapping.S_UOM');
    $qu1 = $this->db->get();
    $result =  $qu1->result_array(); 
    if(!empty($result)){
       $arrReturn = $result;
    }
    return $arrReturn;
 }
```

In this case if data which will be available from query will be passed to place where it is called from.

And in case no data are found then blank array will be passed.

Hope this helps you.